# How Can I make multiple payments in paypal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I try to use PayPal payments API to provide parrallel payments to the multiple merchants in the single checkout. I want use this on marketplace and I want to make payments from one buyer to several sellers without intermediate account, How Can I do this?

I considered the payouts (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/api-integration/#prerequisites), but I can use this way only on my paypal account

```
"items": [
    {
      "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
      "amount": {
        "value": "9.87",
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "note": "Thanks for your patronage!",
      "sender_item_id": "201403140001",
      "receiver": "receiver2@example.com"
    },
    {
      "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
      "amount": {
        "value": "9.85",
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "note": "Thanks for your patronage!",
      "sender_item_id": "201403140001",
      "receiver": "receiver@example.com"
    }
```

I want send post like this, for one customer on my website and several seller.

Comment: That involves splitting payments so we've got multi-vendors and thus it requires PayPal for Partners concepts applied. As a middleman, why don't you try it with zero commission on your side?